# How to play media in link (vlc module)

Tags: python, python-vlc

I'm working on a program which lets you search for a videos/movies from a website and play it directly to vlc. I'm a complete beginner and would appreciate any sort of help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python to do that in a kodi addon called livestreamspro.
LSP is working with Your xml and python code.
Then you can use vlc as external player of kodi... however the kodi player will manage it alone perfectly.
Considering that your idea is to use py language to extract url and (protected) streams or videos from web. That addon, even discontinued is the one you need.
Kodi 19 uses py3  kodi leia 18.9 is still py 2.7. Both accept addon lsp ... but the py part of the code will b different.